# RewriteCond and ending forward slash

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make my directive ignore an ending forward slash in a URL, even if it is there.

### This code works

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/category1/category2/category3/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^recipient=For\+Boys(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newcategory/for-boys/? [NC,L,R=301]
```

So a starting URL such as:

```
http://www.foo.com/category1/category2/category3/?recipient=For+Boys
```

redirects to

```
http://www.foo.com/newcategory/for-boys/
```

---

### The Issue

However my problem arrises when the starting URL is:

```
http://www.foo.com/category1/category2/category3?recipient=For+Boys
```

Note the missing forward slash between `category3?recipient=For+Boys`

What should I put in the first `RewriteCond` to have the redirect work if there is or is not an ending forward slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

[.htaccess regular expression need to make trailing forward slash optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194397/htaccess-regular-expression-need-to-make-trailing-forward-slash-optional)

> Just put /? before the $ at the end in your pattern:

So my new first RewriteCond is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/category1/category2/category3/?$ [NC]
```

Comment: Correct. "?" means to match the preceeding character by either one or zero.

Comment: But you don't need the stuff you quoted. Just add "?" to your original first line.