# RewriteRule not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create friendly urls with .htaccess. I have checked and if I put deny from all on my .htaccess it does not load the webpage proving that the .htaccess is working.

I also have verified that mod-rewrite module is loaded on php using phpinfo
The problem is that when I access the url http://128.199.62.16/web/grupo/asd/123 it say not found and when i try with http://128.199.62.16/web/grupo/index.php?id=asd&description=123 it works as expected

Here you can find my .htaccess file content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^web/grupo/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ web/grupo/index.php?id=$1&descripcion=$2
Options -Indexes
ServerSignature Off
```

Can you please help me :D

Comment: in the root dir /var/www/html/

Comment: Is `/var/www/html/web/grupo/` a valid directory?

Comment: yes it is if I access ussing http://128.199.62.16/web/grupo/index.php?id=asd&description=123 it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file `/var/www/html/web/grupo/.htaccess` if it doesn't exist with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /web/grupo/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&descripcion=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: great thanks. The actual issue was that I have the same .httaccess on the group folder. Changed and now is working

Answer (score 0):

Your input URL does not have a trailing slash, but your rule expects one.
I suggest putting a question mark after the trailing slash to indicate that it is optional.
Also, I suggest using `+` instead of `*` to indicate "one or more" rather than "zero or more".

```
RewriteRule ^web/grupo/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ web/grupo/index.php?id=$1&descripcion=$2
```

For further reference, see:
[trailing slash optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194397/htaccess-regular-expression-need-to-make-trailing-forward-slash-optional)

Comment: changed same result ... what ca i do?